# Can some one help me implement an action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Can some one help me implement an action bar from start to finish including helping me getting one working in my app?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @pdiddy I have tried that and I'm still stuck and this action bar is for os 2.3 and under

Comment: action bar is new in 3.0

Comment: Your question is far too broad, especially given that you want more than the full answer below.  You should probably hire a programmer to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    CreateMenu(menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    return MenuChoice(item);
}

private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item 1");
    {
        mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Item 2");
    {
        mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('b');
        mnu2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Item 3");
    {
        mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('c');
        mnu3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    MenuItem mnu4 = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Item 4");
    {
        mnu4.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    }
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Item 5");
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Item 6");
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Item 7");
}
private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 1",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 2",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 3",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 3:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 4",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 4:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 5",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 5:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 6",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case 6:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Item 7",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: na man this not explaining how to implement it..??

Comment: what do you mean how to implement it? if you run this code, you will see the action bar with a list of item. Not sure what you are asking anymore

Comment: Or did you mean how to create from scratch an action bar for android under 3.0 version ???? is that what you meant?

Comment: yea like how to implement the actionbar Sherlock(Action bar) idk how to do it because every time I try it I fail or how to implement the one from the android v4 compatible library.

Comment: try using this library then : http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/action-bar-sherlock-project-for-action.html